# Flask - How to remove format extention like .json from URL before route matching

Tags: python, flask

Is there any simple way to strip request extensions (like .**json**, .**xml**) from URL before route match like

`/users/1/books.json`

`/users/1/books.xml`

so that I will not have to write multiple routes,

```
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books.json"
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books.xml"
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books"
def user_books(user_id):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to make it another parameter, then test within the method:

```
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books<format>"
def user_books(user_id, format):
    if format == ".json":
        # ...
```

If you want Flask to check against the approved list for you and return 404 NOT FOUND for garbage formats, you can use the `any` converter to list them explicitly:

```
@frontend.route("/test/<user_id>/books<any('.json', '.xml', ''):format>")
def test(user_id, format):
    # ...
```

See [URL route registrations documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the formats in the route:

```py
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books.<format>"
def user_books(user_id, format):
  # Code goes here
```

You might need to setup another route for the default case if you want to support an url without the extension:

```py
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books", defaults={'format':'json'})
```

End result:

```py
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books", defaults={'format':'json'})
@app.route("/users/<user_id>/books.<format>"
def user_books(user_id, format):
   # your code goes here
```